# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, indexing, append

I have an **array of array's** named `pdf` of `len(pdf) = 300`

`pdf[0]` is an array of `len(pdf[0]) = 300`

What I would like to do is, take the `sum of pdf[0][50:100]` and repeat the same for `pdf[1][50:100]` and so on upto `pdf[300][50:100]`.

What I tried is:

```
for i,a in enumerate(pdf):
    result.append(a[i][50:100].sum())
```

But I get the error:
**`IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable`**

Comment: Are you talking about numpy arrays or python lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to build a simple list, then a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is your friend:

`result = [i[50:100].sum() for i in pdf]`

Should do it.

In your for loop,

`a` is `pdf[0], pdf[1]...`
 `i` is `0,1...`

so you are referencing `pdf[0][0][50:100], pdf[1][1][50:100]...` hence the tracebck.

This means you could also have changed your loop to:

```
result = []
for a in (pdf):
    result.append(a[50:100].sum())
```

...but that's what list comprehensions are for :)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
for i,a in enumerate(pdf):
    result.append(a[i][50:100].sum())
```

`a` is actually `pdf[0]`, `pdf[1]`, etc. So you calculate sums of `pdf[0][0]`, `pdf[1][1]`, etc.

If you want: *take the sum of `pdf[0][50:100]` and repeat the same for `pdf[1][50:100]` and so on upto `pdf[300][50:100]`*

you can do

```
result = [a[50:100].sum() for a in pdf]
```